# Is it possible to use jQuery on filters (B.E.F.) in a view?

Tags: javascript, views

I am trying to add some special behaviours with jQuery to input type checkboxes in a view (using better exposed filters).
Ideally i need to make inactive all checkboxes when one of them is clicked. I`ve written a script but it did not do anything.
So i added a simple another code via drupal_add_js in template.php just to see whether it would be working:

```
jQuery('input#myid').click(function(){
alert("clicked");
});
```

it didn`t work and i am asking is it possible to use jQuery on checkboxes in a view?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this D7? I've noticed that with D7 you have to be a bit more careful with setting up external jQuery. Something like this usually works wonders: `(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.putSomethingUniqueHere= {
        attach: function(context, settings) { //code here, you can use $ }}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to write jQuery in drupal 7:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.functionname = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      // some code, with $
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```